# Trying to access error response 500 axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am not able to access the response of error - 500 in axios

```
export const dowloadFilePDF = (data) => {
  return axios
    .request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${basePath + data[0]}`,
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: { Authorization: Authorization },
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      let fileName = response.headers['content-disposition']?.split(';')[1]?.split('=')[1]?.split('"').join('')
      fileName = fileName ? fileName : 'data.pdf'
      fileDownload(response.data, fileName)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data)
    })
}
```

I am not getting the response instead its returning as

```
data : Blob {size: 215, type: 'application/json'}
```

Comment: you just need to show error in your catch(error)=>{ console.log(error)}

Comment: Hi @saliksaleem, when i console.log(error) i get this result - Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: This can't be your actual code, there's a missing `)` on one of the `split` calls. (Or rather, *not* on one of the `split` calls. :-) ) Retyping code you're having trouble with when asking about it is never a good idea, always use copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), you can't assume `error.response` will be filled in. Here's the code the documentation shows with the inline comments explaining it:

> **Handling Errors**
>
> ```
> axios.get('/user/12345')
>   .catch(function (error) {
>     if (error.response) {
>       // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
>       // that falls out of the range of 2xx
>       console.log(error.response.data);
>       console.log(error.response.status);
>       console.log(error.response.headers);
>     } else if (error.request) {
>       // The request was made but no response was received
>       // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
>       // http.ClientRequest in node.js
>       console.log(error.request);
>     } else {
>       // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
>       console.log('Error', error.message);
>     }
>     console.log(error.config);
>   });
> ```

There's another aspect to this as well: You're calling `catch` on the promise returned by `then`, not on the promise returned by axios. If the axios promise is rejected, you'll reach that rejection handler, but you'll **also** reach it if the axios promise is fulfilled but then your fulfillment handler throws an error (or returns a promise it ultimately rejects). In that latter case, the error probably won't have a `response` property at all.

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder is there any possible way to get response i tried the above solution i am not getting the response

Comment: @tinyVariant - Again: There may not be one, depending on what went wrong. See the comments in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to catch errors instead of trying a lot of lines of code in the catch method by promise is using the tools in the Axios names interceptor.

interceptor has two property request and response. In response we can simulate the errors status and based on the status code we can do whatever we want. for example :

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
console.log("error : " , error);
const expectedError = error.response && error.response.status >= 400 && 
 error.response.status < 500;
if (expectedError) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
alert("unexpected error is happen");
});
```

if you need more help [here is the original link](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)